# Does zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(), len) need to be closed or garbage collected automatically?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I'm having an argument with a friend, over possible wasted resources in Go.

Does a Reader have to be closed, if it's operating over an in-memory byte array?

```
func readJar(zipBytes []byte, readMeta bool) (m jar.Manifest, err error) {
    reader, err := zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(zipBytes), int64(len(zipBytes)))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    for _, file := range reader.File {
        switch file.Name {
        case jar.ManifestPath:
            m, err = readManifest(file)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }
    return
}

func readManifest(file *zip.File) (jar.Manifest, error) {
    reader, err := file.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer reader.Close()
    return jar.ReadManifest(reader)
}
```

Whilst originally it was thought to be a source of File Handle Leaks, something else got the blame.

Will this leak memory, or does Go have sufficient escape analysis / garbage collection that it will be fine?

Comment: Golang is garbage collected language it take cares of unreachable objects. But you should still close your file descriptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Golang compiler takes care for [unreachable variables](https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap):-

> The storage location does have an effect on writing efficient
>   programs. When possible, the Go compilers will allocate variables that
>   are local to a function in that function's stack frame. However, if
>   the compiler cannot prove that the variable is not referenced after
>   the function returns, then the compiler must allocate the variable on
>   the garbage-collected heap to avoid dangling pointer errors. Also, if
>   a local variable is very large, it might make more sense to store it
>   on the heap rather than the stack.

Although Golang contains garbage collection. It would be better to use clean up functions. You can use defer function to close the file at the end of function.

```
defer f.close()
```

Check Documentation for [SetFinalizer](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer) to get more understanding on these concepts:

```
func SetFinalizer(obj interface{}, finalizer interface{})
```

> SetFinalizer sets the finalizer associated with obj to the provided
>   finalizer function. When the garbage collector finds an unreachable
>   block with an associated finalizer, it clears the association and runs
>   finalizer(obj) in a separate goroutine. This makes obj reachable
>   again, but now without an associated finalizer. Assuming that
>   SetFinalizer is not called again, the next time the garbage collector
>   sees that obj is unreachable, it will free obj.

The finalizer runs for an object to check if it is unreachable from the source. It can be used for file descriptors but it would be a mistake to depend on a finalizer to flush an in-memory I/O buffer such as a bufio.Writer, because the buffer would not be flushed at program exit.